# Hotkey to switch between multiple displays in Windows 8.1

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-8.1, hotkeys

I have a PC with a monitor. My PC is connected to my TV via HDMI. When I watch movies I use TV screen. For work and gaming I use my monitor.

I have to open "Screen Resolution" window and select "Show desktop only X" option there in order to switch between my monitor and TV.

I do this often thus a hotkey would be very practical.

Is there any built-in hotkey in Windows 8.1 for this purpose?

If no, can you suggest an alternative method, please?

Comment: Windows 7 uses `Win + P` kind of like `Alt + Tab`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Windows 7/8/10 you can use <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to switch between display options which will behave similarly to pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

This can be first observed in Windows 7

---

Full list of shortcuts and hot keys can be found here:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts#keyboard-shortcuts=windows-8

Specifically under the section called `Windows logo key keyboard shortcuts`

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I used AMD Radeon cards for years, which had "Presets" that you could bind to a key sequence. Now I have Nvidia and I thought I would have to download a 3rd party utility like Ultramon, but I can easily switch between monitors with this shortcut, thanks!