# Screen is not turning on, but touch is working

Tags: display

I connected my laptop to TV using HDMI, I can see that the laptop is working, but its screen wont turn on even so it does respect for touch. My only way to see a display is on TV.

Can I tell for sure it's a hardware problem or could it be I messed up something in the settings?

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/questions/763630/hotkey-to-switch-between-multiple-displays-in-windows-8-1) might help you.

Comment: In my case I can't get laptop working with no screens connected to it. I can tell it's a monitor problem by connecting to TV and testing other functionalities.

Comment: I mean, there must be a key/key-combination to switch brtween multiple monitors.