# Windows 10 - close laptop lid

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, external-display

I have two screens - a laptop and external monitor. Sometimes I want to shut the laptop lid and use ONLY the external monitor. On my old laptop all the Windows would just move over to the external monitor. On my current laptop *(ASUS Zenbook UX430UA-GV232T 14-Inch Full HD Nano Edge Screen (Blue) - (Intel Core i7-7500U, 8GB RAM, 256GB SSD, Bluetooth 4.1, Harman Kardon Speakers, Windows 10))* this does not happen.

Instead windows thinks the laptop monitor is still valid even when the lid is shut
Can I fix this? 
Thanks

(I know about Power Options > Do Nothing...this is NOT my question. Thanks)

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  There isn't really anything to *"fix,"* because nothing is actually broken.  However, other people have asked [similar questions](https://superuser.com/q/1162680/650163) before.  As we determined within that previous question, you could easily create a shortcut that points to `%windir%\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe /external` that will give you the ability to quickly switch to **Second screen only** mode.  When you are ready to switch back, another shortcut configured for `%windir%\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe /extend` can reset everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In the display adapters, you either need to disable the laptop monitor OR just press the Windows Key + P, and scroll through the options and choose Projector mode.