# PC, Multi-Monitor, AutoHotKey, Creating a Toggle hotkey that can switch from PC Screen to Extend

Tags: multiple-monitors, autohotkey, windows-11, desktop-computer, hotkeys

Would someone be able to write me a auto hotkey script so I can use Win+alt+a to toggle the project screen function from PC Screen Only to Extend. I have seen the auto hotkey scripts for an individual switch but not a toggle hot key. I would also like to learn how to do this with my speakers and headset, which I already have hotkeys set up using SoundSwitch.

Comment: Please show the search effort and research you have already done.  If you are referring to a script that almost solves the problem, why not share it and we can try to adapt it to help you.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1162680/is-there-a-windows-10-hotkey-or-shortcut-for-switching-to-a-specific-display

Comment: There is a script for toggle displays but it does not work with AutoHotkey